# Dealing with non-independence in data in negative binomial regression

Tags: mixed-model, autocorrelation, negative-binomial-distribution, independence

I am evaluating an intervention that reduces seclusion in mental health care wards. So, I will be using negative binomial regression to determine if there is a significant difference between intervention and comparison sites in reducing seclusion events. My outcome variable will be seclusion events (SEC) and the predictor will be being in an ward where the intervention has been implemented (INT).

One of the assumptions of negative binomial regression is that there is independence of observation. However, there is a possibility that a person admitted to an intervention ward will be secluded several times over time. As a remedy, I will need to account for the autocorrelation of data. How can I implement this using R? Below is the code thus far for my negative binomial regression using MASS package.

```r
summary(sec1 <- glm.nb(SEC ~ INT, data = full_data))
```

Is it okay to use a random coefficient negative binomial regression model? I have written a sample code below with MRN being the ID of the admitted patient.

```r
model1 <- glmer.nb(SEC ~ INT + (1|MRN), data=full_data)
summary(model1)
```